System.Net.WebRequest is slow with multiple background workers
I have a simple .NET 4.7.2 application that queries OpenAI via API.
To speed up the process, I created several background workers in my application, but after running three, the speed of requests drops drastically. It is not related to rate limit or some slowdown by the service provider, because when I run several instances of my application and run one background worker in each, everything works fast. My PC has i7 with 16 cores and 24 threads
My background workers work in loops and call a function which makes the request:
 Private Sub Worker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Worker1.DoWork
        Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True

        Do While worker.CancellationPending = False
            ...
            Dim GptData = GptFn(title)

            Dim NewTitle As String = GptData.Item1
            Dim Lenght As Integer = Len(GptData)
            Dim InputToken As Integer = GptData.Item2
            Dim OutputToken As Integer = GptData.Item3
            Dim Price As Double = GptData.Item4
            ...
        Loop
End Sub

And this is that function:
Private Function GptFn(title As String) As Tuple(Of String, Integer, Integer, Double)
    Try
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(GPTEndpointURL)
        webRequest.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & OpenAIAPIKey
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        webRequest.Method = "POST"

        Dim data As Byte()
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

        
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)

        webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length

        Using reader As Stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()

            reader.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            reader.Flush()
            reader.Close()

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            response = webRequest.GetResponse()
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim json = sr.ReadToEnd
            Dim Deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GPT)(json)

            Dim NewTitle As String = Deserialize.Choices(0).Message.Content
            Dim InputTokens As Integer = Deserialize.Usage.Prompt_tokens
            Dim OutputTokens As Integer = Deserialize.Usage.Completion_tokens
            Dim Price As Double = ((InputTokens / 1000000) * 0.15) + ((OutputTokens / 1000000) * 0.6)
            Return Tuple.Create(NewTitle, InputTokens, OutputTokens, Price)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Tuple.Create($"Request Error: {ex.Message}", 0, 0, 0.00)
    End Try

End Function

Can .NET 4.7.2 only execute one request at a time? The problem is definitely not due to my hardware or API limits

@WiktorZychla You are contradicting yourself in your comment. How would the service provider even know if the HTTP call they receive comes from the same or from different processes on the client machine?

possible duplicate of Max number of concurrent HttpWebRequests

@GSerg Thank you, Setting a higher value (100) for System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit solved the problem

@GSerg: by service provider I mean here the ServicePointManager class and its limit, I even pointed to same solution you did.

@WiktorZychla Which is then confusing because by service provider the OP meant the provider of the API service, to which you immediately responded with "I bet it is". So you were not responding to what the OP actually said, but made it look like you were. If, reading your comment, one assumes that you meant the same as the OP by service provider, then you are contradicting yourself. And if one assumes by service provider you meant something completely different, then your comment looks rather out of place.

@GSerg: my fault, obviously. Confusing a service provider and a service manager shouldn't ever happen to me and being not a native speaker is not an excuse. I hope you're satisfied. Regards.
